# What are forward and backward passes in neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, conv-neural-network

What is the meaning of *forward pass* and *backward pass* in neural networks?

Everybody is mentioning these expressions when talking about backpropagation and epochs.

I understood that forward pass and backward pass together form an epoch.

Comment: I strongly advise you to read carefully through this article : http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/ It is shown in fantastic and easy undestandable way there.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The **"forward pass"** refers to calculation process, values of the output layers from the inputs data. It's traversing through all neurons from first to last layer.

A loss function is calculated from the output values.

And then **"backward pass"** refers to process of counting changes in weights (de facto *learning*), using gradient descent algorithm (or similar). Computation is made from last layer, backward to the first layer.

Backward and forward pass makes together one **"iteration"**.

---

During one iteration, you usually pass a subset of the data set, which is called **"mini-batch"** or **"batch"** (however, "batch" can also mean an entire set, hence the prefix "mini")

**"Epoch"** means passing the entire data set in batches.
 One epoch contains *(number_of_items / batch_size)* iterations